# How do I find out repeat customers at a per product level, postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm a real novice with SQL, but despite half a day of googling and tutorials I can't quite crack my specific use case.

I would like to know how often customers buy the same product, I have a table with products, containing both a friendly name and corresponding IDs, and another table showing each purchase record that contains the customer ID and the Product ID. Where it gets tricky is - the product name can be the same, but have a different ID depending on the date, eg. "Soap" will appear 4 times, but with 4 different IDs for a period of time so a customer has bought 4 soaps, 2 of one ID and 1 each of another.

My ideal output is something like:

| customerid | productname | Repeats |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | soap | 5 |
| ID2 | soap | 2 |
| ID3 | soap | 3 |

where those customers may have bought soaps from 3 different batches, but all up they have 3 soaps - and that's the number I care about. Been struggling with how to pull this together so any help is super appreciated.

Comment: Please post a sample of your product table that corresponds with your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

**You can do the following for use case:**

```
select customerid, productname, count(*) as repeats 
from yourtable 
group by customerid, productname 
order by customerid;
```